# setBackgroundMessageHandler is not called in terminated state

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use firebase/messaging in my react-native application to receive data-only notifications from firebase.

When a message is received, i'll process the data, update my state and show a local notification with react-native-push-notification if the app is in background or terminated.

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  PushNotification.localNotification({...})
})
```

At the android device everything works perfect in foreground, background and terminated state.

In iOS foreground and background is working.

When the app is terminated i can log the notification in the console (see below) AND **there is a notification sound**. But no local notification is showing up.

When i try to logg the iOS device the console prints following output

```
default 03:51:53.697535+0100 dasd Daemon Canceling Activities: {(
    com.apple.pushLaunch.de.myapp.app:D1FAA2
)}
default 03:51:53.697770+0100 dasd CANCELED: com.apple.pushLaunch.de.myapp.app:D1FAA2 at priority 10 <private>!
```

My message from the server is:

```
const message = {
      data: {
        body: JSON.stringify(msgBody),
        title: title,
      },
      contentAvailable: true,
      priority: "high",
      android: {
        priority: "high",
      },
      apns: {
        headers: {
          "apns-priority": "10",
          "apns-push-type": "alert", //already tried background too
          "apns-topic": "de.myapp.app",
        },
        payload: { aps: { sound: "default", contentAvailable: true } },
      },
 
      tokens: userTokens,
    };
```

It drives me crazy for days now and i cant get it to work.
Every help is appreciated

Comment: Recently I faced this issue in one of my app and was able to fix it by using multiple packages (after a hell lot of trial and error). I used `"@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.4.1", "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.3", "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.8.4"`

Comment: How could you fix it? and your able to resolve messages in terminated state now?

Comment: In background and killed state, notification is handled by iOS. In foreground I used local notification.
In foreground `messaging().onMessage` handler and in background `messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler` is getting executed.

Comment: Message format is,
`{"notification": { "body": "", "title": "" },"content_available": true,"data": { ... },"priority": 10}`

Comment: so you are sending notifcation messages, right? because i need a solution for data-only messages

Answer (score 3):

## Found it!

```
Version 7.18.0 - August 13, 2020 Cloud Messaging
Deprecated setBackgroundMessageHandler. Use the new API onBackgroundMessage instead.
```

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#cloud-messaging_2

Comment: Its giving error undefined is not a function

Comment: I believe this is not for react-native. This is for the server library.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at their documentation they mention intentional holds by the system under some conditions, not limited to...

- When the system receives a new background notification, it discards
  the older notification and only holds the newest one.
- If something force quits or kills the app, the system discards the
  held notification.
- If the user launches the app, the system immediately delivers the
  held notification.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app

Comment: But how can Apps as Facebook etc.then still send push notifications if the app is terminated